# Override a new button by lightning component

Tags: lightning

I am working on a customer community using Customer Service (Napili) template. I have a requirement to override the new button of custom object so that some of the details can be auto-populated based on login user. I get to know standard new button cannot be overridden using lightning component the only way i could figure out is to disable the standard button and create a new Lightning component then add it to the custom content layout of record list view. Is there any better workaround to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, you can leverage global actions for this purpose instead of adding component as suggested in the question. So as per your suggestion you will need to hide New button and create a global action for the same. The global action opens in a modal and hence is consistent with the standard LEX New button experience.
For reference regarding global actions follow these great Trailhead posts:
[Understanding How Actions Work in Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/lex_migration_customization/lex_migration_customization_actions) and
[Configure Components for Custom Actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_config_action.htm)
If this doesn't answer your question please elaborate on it so that I can help properly.